# Display profile data LinkedIn Api without authentication

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Quick questions, but can I display profile data from my own LinkedIn page on a website through the JavaScript SDK, without having the user login through the authentication layer ?

I don't want to display any other information other than from my profile, I was under the impression this is possible without a user logging in.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk

I have connected correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxXXXxxxXXXxxx
    onLoad: linkedInLoaded
</script>
```

but then using the follow:

```
IN.API.Profile("me").fields([]);
```

Tells me I require authentication.

Comment: How should the programme know your profile is that one you are fetching? If there is a security layer it is the same for all the users.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I thought it may know because I have created an application on my user login which the API_KEY links to.

Comment: Ah, then it should had been possible. Is your purpose only getting your profile? or do you want to get some others?

Comment: Purely, display profile data in a HTML page and style with CSS. 

Basically an about page for a portfolio without having to duplicate data, it just pulls from LinkedIn.

So obviously you can see why authentication isn't needed.

Comment: You have to look for an API of linked in or something that provides you access to the user portfolio without logging in. By the way, i think you can only se a user profile if you have logged in, but I have only a vague idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @CHEWX I misunderstood your original question. Yes, you are correct, what you are trying to do is not possible. What are you looking for is the ability to make an unauthenticated call to pull any random profile (and for your use-case, you would always be pulling your own profile). However, LinkedIn does not have any unauthenticated APIs available.

The only thing that comes close to what you are looking for is a drop-in plugin which you can find here: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile

You could build some service that makes an authenticated REST call to pull your profile every so often, and then push the updated profile info to wherever you are saving it to display it on your website.

Comment: Ok @Arash, so what I am trying to do is impossible as the user once logged in will see their own "ME" data, not mine. And you cannot fetch the data without logging ?